# Why expression of variables of specified type (Number) converts to string in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I get confused with the result of the expression in TypeScript.

```
selectedLocaleForm: number = 0;
locales: number[] = [0, 1];

index(index: number)` {
    let result = index * this.locales.length + this.selectedLocaleForm;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
```

When I pass 0 to the function it returns 0 as expected.
Why does the function `index` return '01' when `this.selectedLocaleForm` is updated in HTML select block?

Comment: One of those values is actually a string. If you're saying that `this.selectedLocaleForm` is updated from the HTML, then I'd assume it's that one. The values in the HTML are always strings, you should be converting to numbers first.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, it sounds logically and it works if I am converting ``this.selectedLocaleForm``. But why should I covert it manully if I declared if as a number>

Comment: The type system only exists at compile time, not at runtime. It's there to ensure that the code *looks* correct. However, the compiler can be mislead. For example `foo: string = "hello"; bar: number = foo as string;` will overrule the compiler and assert that the assignment is correct when that's not actually the case. Another example might be assigning an `any` value since that is allowed to be assigned to anything. These gaps in the compiler's checks are where things can go wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the function index return '01' when this.selectedLocaleForm is updated in HTML select block

Because `this.selectedLocaleForm` is a `string`.

## But `selectedLocaleForm` is typed `number`

That may very well be. But its easy to still force a string into it e.g.

```
this.selectedLocaleForm = 'some string` as unknown as string;
```

In your case the string is most likely being injected by your HTML template.

## Fix

Annotate `selectedLocaleForm` as a string and convert it to a number using `+` as shown below:

```
selectedLocaleForm: string = '0';
locales: number[] = [0, 1];

index(index: number)` {
    let result = index * this.locales.length + (+this.selectedLocaleForm);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
```